# How to get EC2 instance private IP in a private subnet?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a python application which is running inside a docker container using Beanstalk in a private subnet, and I want to get the Private/Local IP of the EC2 instance. Is it possible to get the Local IP address without using `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4` inside a docker container.

Although I tried `docker run --net=host <image_name>` but still its not accessible.

Comment: Are you saying that you are able to retrieve the IP from the metadata service, but you don't want to? Why?

Comment: then add environment varialbe in the container like `HOST_IP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)` and use the `HOST_IP` in the container. so you will get fron ENV

Comment: @jarmod, sorry for the confusion. Actually am afraid that the metadata service won't work in case of private subnets if am not wrong or will it work ?.

Comment: It aws service and it should work in every case

Comment: Ok thanks @Adiii, but incase if I dont want to use that URL is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Yes but again u need to cat the file but I would prefer to use curl or pass curl call to env

Comment: Did the env tricks work?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the local ip of a Linux instance with this command:

`hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'`

For EB, use .ebexentions and write a bash script in a script_name.config to run: `export HOST_IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Just curious I tried `--net=host` in `docker run`, but it picked up the docker IP instead of the host IP, where it should use the host network stack right ! but what I did wrong here ?